# How add tables to existing EF Core 3.0 context by PM console?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to add new tables to my `dbContext`. Can I do via the package management console?

For clarity, this is my command for the scaffold:

```
PM> `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=dbServer;Database=myAppDb;User Id=UserAppdb;
Password=MyPass;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t Users, Devices, 
Items -context "AppdbContext"`
```

Comment: I think you must use Migration when you are adding new tables.

Comment: for learning code-first approach follow this: https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-code-first

Comment: What is your use case? Do you already have the table in the db and now you want to add it to the dbContext, or do want to add an entirely new table to both?

Comment: @Zavog the first case, table already in DB and now I want to add it to the dbContext

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi sorry I wasn't very clear in my question, my case is database first. The creation of the context has already taken place but I have "forgotten" a table that already exists in SQLServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework Core encourages you to use the code-first approach and migrations (as mentioned in the comments to your question). The database-first approach is not really supported, but you can work your way around it:

I would suggest that you re-execute your scaffolding command in a new solution and then copy the new classes that represent the new tables to your original solution (you might have to adapt their namespaces)
If your new tables have relations to any tables that previously existed, you'll have to adapt their corresponding classes as well by adding the navigation Properties.
Then you have to add a DbSet for each newly added class in your DbContext.
Then you have to modify the OnModelCreating() method in your DbContext (You can probably just copy the contents of the newly generated one.

Generally you should consider applying the code-first approach in the future, especially if you want to ship your application to customers. With code-first, you never modify the database directly, but you only modify your code by adding classes and registering them in your DbContext.

Comment: Thank you, a clear and well explained answer. The copy and paste solution is fine for me.
The database first approach is not recommended but my project requires the use of tables already existing in the company database, I would like to know if I have wrong approach to my project by not recreating the tables?

Comment: If it is not in your power to decide how the tables are defined in the company database, then keep following the database first approach and don't use migrations. In any other case it would be easier for you in the long run if you follow this: https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-code-first
Be aware that the link describes how to create the initial migration. Everytime you want to adapt the database, you'll need another one.
By following this approach, you can define your tables in code (as you have to anyway) and let EF-Core create the table in the db.

Answer (score 0):

PM> get-help scaffold-dbcontext –detailed

Answer (score 0):

you were close! 
You should specify -t for each table so in your case it will be:

```
`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=dbServer;Database=myAppDb;User Id=UserAppdb; Password=MyPass;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t Users -t Devices -t Items -context "AppdbContext"`
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion but the code I wrote worked for the creation of my context, now I would like to add a table that is already present in SQLServer, you say that just rewrite it but also specifying the new table to add it?

Comment: sorry if I was mistaken, I put what the documentation says here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet . Your reasoning is CORRECT, you need to add the new table name to the command  -t newtablename. If it worked, please flag the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Docs you can do that in the Package Manager Console with the scaffold command by adding the suffix "-Force" at the end. The command should include the existing table names as well, along with the new tables that you want to add. Otherwise, (meaning if you type only the new tables and omit the existing) the new tables will be added but the existing ones will be removed from the Context.cs file and you will have to add them manually.

Refer here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=vs#updating-the-model